# VueJS - What's the best alternative to a long list of v-if's

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dynamic-forms

I need to make a dynamic form where an admin area allows someone to add and re-arrange fields in a form. Each field has a type: date,checkbox,select,text,number etc. I've created separate components for each field type but now my form looks something like this (pseudo code to give an example).

```
<section v-for="field in fields">
    <field-date v-if="field.type === 'date'" v-model="field.value"></field-date>
    <field-select v-if="field.type === 'select'" v-model="field.value"></field-select>
    <field-number v-if="field.type === 'number'" v-model="field.value"></field-number>
    <field-text v-if="field.type === 'text'" v-model="field.value"></field-text>
    <field-checkbox v-if="field.type === 'checkbox'" v-model="field.value"></field-checkbox>
</section>
```

But this is already getting unwieldy and will only get more out of control. But I can't find a simpler way of doing this. Perhaps field should be an object with a render method? But then the if/else is just going to be abstracted elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

```
<section v-for="field in fields">
    <component :is="'field-' + field.type" v-model="field.value"></component>
</section>
```

Comment: There are a lot of hidden gems in the vue docs. You just need to dig for it :)